# Error while installing Passenger + Nginx on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

This is the code that I'm running
`sudo apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger` 
This is the output that I'm getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libnginx-mod-http-passenger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `phusionpassenger` repository to ubuntu manually first as explained in [Installing Passenger on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/advanced_guides/install_and_upgrade/nginx/install/oss/jammy.html):

```
curl https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/auto-software-signing-gpg-key.txt | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/phusion.gpg >/dev/null

# Add our APT repository
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jammy main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'
sudo apt-get update

# Install Passenger + Nginx module
sudo apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger
```